# Using a regular expression to find words with lower and upper case characters in parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2013

I'm creating a program that searches a string for finding words that are in parenthesis with lower and upper case characters but I can't seem to figure out what regular expression to use.  Example word - (LowerUpper)

regular expression :

```
string upperLowerParens = "\\([A-Z][a-z][a-z]+[A-Z]+\\)";
```

Comment: Would you also expect (LOWERUPPER), (lowerupper), ( LowerUpper ), etc to match? Can you provide the input strings for testing, and those that you would expect to match or fail?

Comment: Well It would be a string in parenthesis with no space like "(LowerUpper)"

Comment: I'd basically only want to look for that case of just (LowerUpper)

Comment: No [rosé wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ros%C3%A9) for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
\(([A-Z]+[a-z]+)[A-za-z]*\)|\(([a-z]+[A-Z]+[A-za-z]*)\)
```

- **Explanation**

this is divided into two parts if one of them is matched the word between brackets will be matched

1. `\(([A-Z]+[a-z]+)[A-za-z]*\)` this validates something like `(LowerUpper)` where capital letters appears first
2. `\(([a-z]+[A-Z]+[A-za-z]*)\)` this validates something like `(upperLower)` where lower case letters appears first

f you want to allow spaces after and before brackets you can change your regex to be something like this `\( *([A-Z]+[a-z]+)[A-za-z]* *\)|\( *([a-z]+[A-Z]+[A-za-z]*) *\)`

check the demo here [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU6eC4/1)

Answer (score -1):

To ensure the word in parentheses has at least one upper and one lower case letter, and contains ONLY letters, you can try (with case-sensitive set)

```
(?=\(.*?[A-Z].*?\))(?=\(.*?[a-z].*?\))\([A-Za-z]+\)
```

Comment: It matches `(UpperLower)`.  If you need something else, you will need to be more specific as to your requirements.

Comment: It will need to be a regex that matches exactly that.  One or more upper case one or more lower case and parenthesis

Comment: All you need to do is change the `[^)]` to `[A-Za-z]` to ensure that the ONLY characters in the matched sequence are the enclosing parentheses and upper and lower case letters.  I edited to show that

Answer (score -1):

The problem with my first reg ex posted in the question was it only returned the first three letters.  but I have found this Regex works for the stated example and was verified by regex101.com

```
 [A-Z][a-z][a-z]+[A-Z]+[a-z][a-z]+
```

Comment: This regex does not include a requirement for parentheses; it also requires that the first letter be upper case, and that the last letter be lower case.  None of these parameters were stated in your initial question

Comment: I didn't include the parenthesis but I did try it with the parenthesis and with out and it finds it either way.

Comment: As I wrote, in addition to that, your regex requires that the first letter be upper case, and the last be lower case, and neither of these requirements were stated in your question

Comment: Well considering it is in the sample I posted.

Comment: And there are plenty of items that your regex will match that was not included in your sample `(LowerUpper)`

Comment: Considering I already accepted another answer that already works I'm really confused as to why you're still egging on this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77631/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-crayams).